# Merge hashes and don't overwrite lists inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, we can merge hashes by using the `merge` function:

```
1.9.3-p194 :038 > h1 = { "a" => 1, "b" => [1] }
 => {"a"=>1, "b"=>[1]} 
1.9.3-p194 :039 > h2 = { "a" => 2, "b" => [2] }
 => {"a"=>2, "b"=>[2]} 
1.9.3-p194 :040 > h1.merge(h2)
 => {"a"=>2, "b"=>[2]}
```

Merging overwrites the arrays inside the hashes, but I would like it to join them.

```
 => {"a"=>2, "b"=>[1, 2]}
```

Is there a ruby function or one-liner to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want some thing like this ??

ruby-1.9.2 > a = {:car => {:color => "red"}}
 => {:car=>{:color=>"red"}} 
ruby-1.9.2 > b = {:car => {:speed => "100mph"}}
 => {:car=>{:speed=>"100mph"}} 
ruby-1.9.2 > a.merge(b) {|key, a_val, b_val| a_val.merge b_val }
 => {:car=>{:color=>"red", :speed=>"100mph"}}

Comment: If you have two hashes, options and defaults, and you want to merge defaults into options without overwriting existing keys, what you really want to do is the reverse: merge options into defaults:

options = defaults.merge(options)
Or, if you're using Rails you can do:

options.reverse_merge!(defaults)

Comment: @X-Factor This *is* about option hashes, the ones you pass to `as_json`, that contain `{ except: [:this, :that] }`. I don't want to override the `except`, I want to *add* to the `except`. Your solution doesn't take the arrays into account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add extra behavior to the merge method

```
h1 = { "a" => 1, "b" => [1] }
h2 = { "a" => 2, "b" => [2] }

h1.merge(h2) {|key, first, second| first.is_a?(Array) && second.is_a?(Array) ? first | second : second }
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I didn't know you could pass a block to the `merge` method. And I didn't know the `Array | Array` operator either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a block to [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge), which looks like it was designed especially for cases like this.

```
a = { x: 1, y: [1] }
b = { x: 2, y: [2] }
a.merge(b) {|k, a, b| a.is_a?(Array) && b.is_a?(Array) ? a + b : b}
=> { x: 2, y: [1, 2] }
```

Comment: what if `a = { x: 1, y: [2] }` and `b = { x: 2, y: [2] }`? It will create `{ x: 2, y: [2, 2] }`! shouldn't it be only [2] instead of [2, 2]

Comment: Thanks! With my example your solution yields `{"a"=>2, "b"=>[1, 2, 1]}` though

Comment: @SybariteManoj It really depends on whether he wants to merge or concatenate the contents of the arrays.